# Lua: Calling a dll, getting a result, and a crash

Tags: lua

Win x64, using lua53.exe or lua54.exe; I get a crash after running this.
The DLL test() just returns the value 3

```
test= assert(package.loadlib("jsyslog.dll","test"))
print("Test result ", test()) -- Should be 3
-- displays that twice & crashes
```

The exact output I get:

> Test result     function: 00000000704186d0      Test result     function: 00000000704186d0

So I must be doing something wrong, but I don't understand ...(same thing with lau54, but w/o the crash.)
[image: Text]

Comment: What is `jsyslog.dll`?

Comment: Just the folder the files are in.

Answer (score 0):

Lua is unable to work with arbitrary DLL.
The DLL must be made specially for using with Lua.
The rules to follow when writing a Lua-compatible function inside your DLL, are described in the manual:
https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#lua_CFunction

To communicate with arbitrary DLL, you need FFI library.
For example, LuaJIT has FFI out-of-the-box.
See [this example](http://luajit.org/ext_ffi_tutorial.html) on how `uncompress()` is invoked from `zlib1.dll` using FFI library.